Return Back to the Page which current page called From
I have Page P300 can be called from either page P100 or P200. The c100 Interactive report column  created in page P300. Now I want this column to be shown when its container page called from P100 and hidden when called from any other page.
I used server side condition REQUEST = Value, and use specific request name with url open page P300 from page P100. but the the column always hidden, when I use the opposite condition Request != Value it shown.
Anyone Knows what mistake that was made. Why Show processing had apply the Request != Value condition but had not apply the REQUEST = Value condition.

To find out where it went wrong, spice up the page with calls to apex_debug to see (in debug) what the value is of the REQUEST at different phases during page rendering. However, the easiest solution is to create a page item P300_CALLING_PAGE and set the value in the link to page 300. That is what i've seen in a lot of apps.

After debugging the page, there is nothing anomalous. so I used P300_CALLING_PAGE as what you suggested.
